# finding number binary positions

Tags: c

I have an 8 bit integer for, example  20 (binary - 00010100). How could I go about finding the position of the ones in the number's binary representation? I could do it for a single one using powers of 2 but for multiple one's i'm stuck

Comment: Are you storing this binary number in array?

Comment: How do you want to represent your answer? With an array of numbers? Booleans? You could turn the binary number into a Boolean array trivially by testing the LSB, then right shifting by one and repeating.

Comment: Show your code. It will help us to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just test each bit in a loop, e.g.

```
char val = 0x42;

for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; ++i)
    printf("bit %d = %d\n", i, (val & (1 << i)) != 0);
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; ++i)
    printf("bit %d = %d\n", i, (val >> i) & 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For finding a bit that is set quickly, use this:

```
int oneBit = x & ~(x-1);
```

After this, `oneBit` will have ONLY the lowest bit of `x` set.
(For example, if `x` was `0001 0100`, oneBit will be `0000 0100`)

After that, you can turn off the lowest bit with:

```
x &= x-1;
```

(if `x` was `0001 0100`, new `x` should be `0001 0000`)

Then you can repeat the first operation to find the next lowest bit that was set.

This gets you directly to those bits that are set, and skips bits that are zero.

Here's example code that shows it in action:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 20;  // 0001 0100

    while (x)
    {
        printf("Low Bit is: %d\n", x & ~(x-1));
        x &= (x-1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Low Bit is: 4    // eg. 0000 0100
Low Bit is: 16   // eg. 0001 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do a cycle and check for each 1 in turn. If the result you expect is a list of the positions you can go no better than linear complexity as the answer may be linear itself.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```
int myNum = 123;
int isOne[32];
for(int ii=0; ii<32; ii++) {
  isOne[ii] = (myNum & 1)?1:0;
  myNum = myNum >> 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is quite a short answer:

```
    for(int i=0;x;x>>=1)
       printf("Bit %d is: %d\n", i++, x & 1);
```

So for this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 20;  // 0001 0100

    for(int i=0;x;x>>=1)
       printf("Bit %d is: %d\n", i++, x & 1);

   return 0; 
}
```

[you get](http://ideone.com/zz44az)

```
Bit 0 is: 0
Bit 1 is: 0
Bit 2 is: 1
Bit 3 is: 0
Bit 4 is: 1
```

for positions:

```
    for(int i=0;x;x>>=1,i++)
       if(x&1)
          printf("Bit set at position %d\n", i);
```